# Why can't I add any more user?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multi-user

I have an Asus tablet with Lollipop on it.

Two week ago I was able to create another user on that device.
Now I want to edit another user but touching the lowermost bar does not start any action. (the text is greyed out, i don't know, if that was the case also two weeks ago)

[image]

I already contacted Asus support and they said, this feature had been removed by Anroid and they can't do anything.

I checked the build.prop and it does not contain a single entry for fw.xxx

Any idea, why I can't add another user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've reached the maximum numbers of users supported for your device. [That's why the entry is grayed out](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/lollipop-release/src/com/android/settings/users/UserSettings.java#215). You can attempt to confirm this by executing the following command in a terminal emulator app or through [adb](/questions/tagged/adb):

```
pm get-max-users
```

If it shows `Maximum supported users: 2` (Guest user is not included in maximum limit, so it doesn't matter whether it is setup or not; Primary user/Owner is included in the limit) then you know you hit the wall. The limit is [set by the manufacturer](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html#applying_the_overlay).

Example for Nexus 6 running Android 5.0:

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: You are right. My device is set to 2 users. Is there any way to increase this limit?

Comment: I do not know a way as of now. BTW, if I've satisfactorily answered your original question, then you may consider [accepting](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer by clicking the check-mark right below the downward icon.

Comment: You are right, the original question is completly answered. Sorry. Here comes the check-mark