# How can I enable the "Add user or profile" option on Lolipop (Asus Zenpad S 8) - fw.max_users?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, restricted-profiles

Hi I have been setting up Parental Control for a 9 year old kid on an Asus ZenPad S 8.0, which has Android 5.0 Lolipop installed.

I created a restricted account for him but tinkered trying to remove the guest option as he could bypass security by creating a temporary guest account.

In the end a part from install some aps like Time Limit, Screen Time, Internet Security, Family Time... I didn't actually do much as at some point after trying many different tools () I realised the tablet had to be rooted in order for the guest account to be disabled as described in this article http://slashgenie.com/how-to-disable-creation-of-android-guest-accounts-on-lollipop/
I decided not to root it as I am new to Android and I understood this voids the warranty and can create a "brick" :(

The strange thing is that now with the main owner/admin account I can create guest accounts but I can't create new accounts (I want to create another restricted account for his brother).

The "Add user or profile" option is disabled. This guy seems to have a similar problem [Why can't I add any more user?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143556/why-cant-i-add-any-more-user)
But I only have two users the admin + the kid. Maybe with my tinkering of file explorer apps and sql editors I did actually manage to reduce the number of accounts to 1 (my original intention with fw.max_users=1)... but this should have show up on the file build.prop, which it doesn't, and how could I do that as my device is not rooted!?

Comment: doh! I just downloaded an emulator and ran pm get-max-users... and found out I can only install 2 users...

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. Anyhow, after making restricted profile if you want the kid not be able to create Guest account than I suggest you first remove/delete Guest account if it is already available, by logging into it and choosing to delete it. Afterwards, using [tag:adb] issue the command: `adb shell settings put global guest_user_enabled 0`. Root is not required and from then on you won't be able to create a Guest account unless you revert 0 with 1.

Comment: I had deleted the guest account and then from the restricted account it was no longer possible to create a guest account.

I have given up on making the non restricted  account safe...As the device is limited to 2 users they will just have to share the restricted account.
How to let the restricted account update the apps that are already installed? The kids want to play Clash of Clans which has regular updates. When 1 is available it doesn't let them play and says that they do not have the correct permissions in google play.I would like them to be able to update apps already installed